# How to assign value to variable inside imread function?

Tags: python

I want to open multiple images in a loop. I have named the images number wise(1,2,3...) and want to open that image through code. This is what i tried

```
for i in range(1,10):
    img=cv2.imread('i.jpg')
```

Comment: try `img = cv2.imread(str(i)+'.jpg')`

Comment: you should use `str.format` [here](https://pyformat.info/) is a quick guide on how to do that. an instant answer would be `'{}.jpg'.format(i)` but you should really take a look at `.format` as its very useful

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need the `i` to be a string. So casting to `string` will solve it.

like this:

```
import cv2
for i in range(1,10):
    img = cv2.imread(str(i)+'.jpg')
```

Comment: thank you very much. It worked.

Comment: Good to hear. Please @radhikabahirat mark it as the accepted answer. It is amazing why someone will downvote this without comments. It really doesnt help anyone.